# Way to remove space between nav-bar and drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to coding and am working on a fictitious website for a restaurant. I can't seem to figure out how to remove the gap between my drop down menu and top navigation bar under the menu section. Ideally I would like the pink drop down box to be directly under the black nav bar. Any suggestions on what I have done wrong? I've played around with margins and padding everywhere. Even did a margin 0 and padding 0 at the start of my CSS page to see if that wold have an effect, it didn't.

Attached is my code for HMTL and CSS

```css
body {
background-color: #41393d;
}

/* Header */

.header {

width: 100%;
height: 50px;
display: block;
background-color: black;
}

.header_content {

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: black;
}

.logo_container {

height: 100%;
display: table;
float: left;
}

.logo {

height: 100%;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
} /* Navigation */

.navigation {

float: right;
height: 100%;
} .navigation li {

float: left;
height: 100%;
display: table-cell;
padding: 0px 20px;
position: relative;
}

a:hover {

color: #8a8c8f !important;
} .navigation li a {

display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
color:#BE1E2D;
font-family: athelas, 
serif; font-style:normal;
text-decoration: none;
} .sub_menu1 {

display: none;
}

.navigation li:hover .sub_menu1 {

display: block;
position: absolute;
background: #d4a18d;
} .navigation li:hover .sub_menu1 ul {

display: inline-block;
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
text-align: center;
}

.navigation li:hover .sub_menu1 ul li {

padding: 5px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
TOWN_Restaurant` <header>
            <div class="header">
                    <div class="header_content">
                            <div class="logo_container">
                                    <img alt="TOWN logo" id="image" class="logo" src="images/town_logo.png">
                            </div>`
             <ul class="navigation">
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="our_story.html">Our Story</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
                                        <div class="sub_menu1">
                                                <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="menu.html">Cuisine</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="menu_2.html">Beverages</a></li>
                                                </ul>

                                        </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>

                        </ul>
                </div>

        </div>

</header>
```

Comment: add top navbar html code

Comment: Hi, part of your html code is missing, we need that to help you with your question

Comment: So weird! It shows on my end. I can't figure out how to add it to original post but here is the missing portion:<header>
                <div class="header">
                        <div class="header_content">
                                <div class="logo_container">
                                        <img alt="TOWN logo" id="image" class="logo" src="images/town_logo.png">
                                </div>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your nav `<ul>` has a margin of 16px for top and bottom while the height is 100% of the parent's height which is 50px so the total height of the `<ul>` is:

**50px** (parent's height) + **16px** (margin-top) + **16px** (margin-bottom) = **82px**

and this is making it get out of the header which has a fixed height of 50px.
To get this fixed, you have to

**1st:** set your nav `<ul>`'s margin to 0 and use padding-top on the `<li>`s instead with their box-sizing value set to border box so that padding doesn't affect the height of the `<li>`s.

**2nd:** set the top of your "sub_menu1" to 100% **(**which is 50px in this case *[the parent's height]***)**  and this will get the the dropdown menu right beneath your navigation.

and here it is working:

```css
body {
  background-color: #41393d;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}

.header_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.logo_container {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Navigation */

.navigation {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation li {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:hover {
  color: #8a8c8f !important;
}

.navigation li a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  color: #BE1E2D;
  font-family: athelas, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub_menu1 {
  display: none;
}

.navigation li:hover .sub_menu1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #d4a18d;
  top: 100%;
}

.navigation li:hover .sub_menu1 ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation li:hover .sub_menu1 ul li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
TOWN_Restaurant`
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_content">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <img alt="TOWN logo" id="image" class="logo" src="images/town_logo.png">
      </div>`
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="our_story.html">Our Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
          <div class="sub_menu1">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="menu.html">Cuisine</a></li>
              <li><a href="menu_2.html">Beverages</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. I would have never known that my <ul> margin was set to 16px. Is this something that happened automatically because I didn't type that out in my code. Were you able to find this out through inspecting?

Comment: Yes, <ul> takes 1em margin by default. which means 1 time of your font-size and since the default font-size is 16px so <ul>s get a margin of 16px. And Yeah, I had to inspect your navigation to figure out what the problem was and it turned out that you forgot to reset the <ul>. Usually, when we use a <ul> we reset its padding, margin and list-style.

Comment: Gotcha! Do you happen to know why my website then displays differently amongst different browsers? For instance in Chrome and Firefox, the adjusted CSS displays exactly how I want, but in in Safari, there is still a gap.